# "Teaching to fish..." answers, or when an answer is how to find the answer

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Recently I stumbled across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25444127/3366929) where the OP posted a block of code that did not reproduce the symptoms he described.

Normally I'd just have left a comment saying the code worked for and voted to close.

However, in this particular question came from a 500+ rep user -- someone who wasn't totally new to Stack Overflow and I figured I'd throw a bone.

I left an answer that wasn't an answer -- but was too long for a comment.

What was the best approach here?

- Vote to close as no reproducible and nothing more?
- Squeezed my "answer" into a hard-to-read and comment?
- Left my answer *and* voted to close?

(PS, I swear I'm not doing this for the Meta effect ;) )

Comment: You teached him to use a debugger, great answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Now, this particular question you linked cannot have an answer, because it does not have the V part in [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

But if the question in question has an answer, but the OP is missing something obvious, you can throw the bone first, and then...

> you can hide the answer inside a [spoiler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers).

Comment: Evil genius use of the spoiler tag.

Comment: ... although the spoiler tag needs to be declared, otherwise people will hover over just because they're wondering what the grey box is for. Like I did just now!

Comment: @halfer it should be pretty obvious, ████ ███████, no?

Answer (score 6):

Quite commonly someone may be expert in one technology and a complete novice in another, so they may well get rep answering questions in their field of expertise and then come across as a total idiot in the one where they ask the question. I know I am very non-expert outside of C++ and could well be asking newbie questions if I have to use a technology.

Of course I know that most of the time I search and already find the question and the answer, and of course none of you knew I ever did that as although I upvote the answer nobody can see where I have upvoted. Perhaps I should upvote any question that ends up as a "me too" question.

I see the user has posted a block of code, and I haven't run it to see if it reproduces the symptoms the user suggests.

The "it works for me" concept means that perhaps the bug is elsewhere, but of course the OP doesn't know that and thinks it is in his code.

Comment: Off topic: I _would_ upvote a "me too" question because, it is useful, to _me_.

Comment: Yes, one should, and that should be the purpose of upvoting questions. Are users here really "trained" to do that?

Comment: No clue, but I also usually upvote questions that incite answers that help me. I view as a "thanks for asking this".

Comment: I would agree with you on most days. In this particular case, however, the code was minimal enough that one doesn't need much skill to grasp it all, and verifying it with the proper tools was one hit of a key away.